# VBScript: Displaying swedish characters (äåö)

Tags: vbscript

Following VBScript reads txt file and prints its contents. But, it does not show characters such as äåö. Can someone help me to know how to read?

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
inputDir = "c:\input\" 
inpFile = ""
inpFileCount = 0

Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(inputDir) 
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files 
    If LCase(objFS.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "txt" Then 
        inpFile = objFile.Path 
        inpFileCount = inpFileCount + 1
    End If 
Next

If inpFileCount > 1 Then
    WScript.Quit(1)
End If

Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(inpFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If strLine <> Empty Then 
        WScript.Echo strLine
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: How are you running this? On a webpage or as a script on your computer? When running it on my machine as a stand alone script it works fine. I get åäö.

Comment: @WozzeC: I run it as stand alone script. I do not get any åäö. What could be the reason?

Comment: Not sure, I tested changing encoding on my text file and that gave me different results. Open the txt in notepad++ and look down in the right corner to se what encoding it has. Test to set the encoding to ISO 8859-1 by clicking Encoding > Character sets > Western european > ISO 8859-1 and try the script again.

Comment: Alternatively just do Encoding > Convert to ANSI

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by just copying the file to destination. Though it is not good, but it works for me.

```
If objFS.FileExists(inpFile) Then 
    destinationFile = "D:\Test\refkoder.txt"
    objFS.CopyFile inpFile, destinationFile, True 
End If
```